# CSS - Move text without moving block

Tags: html, css

I style few things on place i want to, things looks cool but i need to move a short text inside a "buble". To make it looks like:
[image]

But atm it looks like :
[image]

My CSS:

```
#news #right ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */ 
    background-image: url("images/black_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #898989;
    height:45px;
    width: 569px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border 1px;
    border-color: #898989;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
#news #right ul li:hover{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */ 
    background-image: url("images/blue_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height:45px;
    width: 569px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border 1px;
    border-color: #898989;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}  
#news #right ul li a:visited{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul li a:active{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul li a:link{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul{
    padding 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.newsheading{
    background-image: url("images/cs_icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
}    

#news #right ul li:hover .newsheading{
    color: #FFFFFF;         
}

 #news #right ul li .blue-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/blue_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 31px;
    height: 46px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 568px;
    display: none;     
}
#news #right ul li:hover .blue-arrow{
    display: inline-block; 
}

 #news #right ul li .balloon{
    width: 32px; 
    height: 27px; 
    background-image: url("images/white_buble.png");
    margin-left: 250px;
    display: none; 
}
#news #right ul li:hover .balloon{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #1d5f97; 
}
 #news #right ul li .blueballoon{
    width: 32px; 
    height: 27px; 
    background-image: url("images/blue_buble.png");
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#news #right ul li:hover .blueballoon{
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

My HTML Looks like:

```
  <span id="right">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

The text in bubles are moved out and i need to change it, is here somebody who can help me with that? Also i have problem with change text color when hover up, even if i set on #FFFFFF in hover:newsheading

Live preview can be find on:
http://funedit.com/andurit/try2/

Thanks for reading this post :)

Comment: Just to warn you - using balloon as image may be wrong. What if number is too long i.e. 2333435?

Comment: its number of comments, it shouldnt have more then 99 :), is there any other way how to do it without using CCS3 or JS?

Comment: There is no need to avoid using CSS3 or JS, but yes there is solution without CSS3, using sprites. Google "sliding doors css".

Comment: Thanks for your recommanding

Answer (score 2):

```
#news #right ul li .blueballoon {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Ohoo that simple? You are damm right man! Can u help me to set WHITE color on text when its :hover?